# Correct logic and set of time for variable

Tags: php

I have 3 functions `work()`, `timeLimits()`, and `search()`. I'm trying to do some check in `timeLimits()` and if some of the returns are true the script becomes blocked for a certain time.

Everything works fine with checks and blocks. What isn't working is updating the variable which holds the time until when will be blocked and checking when the block ends.

So, here are the functions:

```
const TOTAL_BLOCK_TIME = 20; // sec
const TOTAL_OPERATING_TIME_BEFORE_BLOCK = 10; // sec


    private $worker;
    private $startTime;
    private $afterBlock;
    private $isBlocked = false;
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->worker->addServer();
        $this->worker->addFunction("myfunction", array($this, "search"));
        $this->startTime = time();
        $this->afterBlock = time() - 1;
    }

public function work()
{
   while (true) {
      $this->worker->work();
   }
}

public function timeLimits()
{
    $currentTime = time();
    $timePassed = $currentTime - $this->startTime;
    
    if ($timePassed > self::TOTAL_OPERATING_TIME_BEFORE_BLOCK) {
       $this->afterBlock = $currentTime + self::TOTAL_BLOCK_TIME;
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public function search($job)
{
        
    if ( $this->timeLimits() ) {
        return 'Blocked until:'.$this->afterBlock; 
    } 
    // db query, the rest of the code
    // it wont be executed if $this->timeLimits() return true
}
```

The problem: When `timeLimits()` return true and the script is blocked each new request updates the `$this->afterBlock` again. I guess is because I have `$this->afterBlock = $currentTime + self::TOTAL_WORKER_SLEEP_TIME;` in the if condition and each time it is in the condition the variable gets an update.

What I don't know is how to update this variable only once e.g. when it is entered in the condition, not every time I call `if ( $this->timeLimits() ) { ... }`

Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a flag to keep track of the block status and update the `$this->afterBlock` only when the flag is false.

```
const TOTAL_BLOCK_TIME = 20; // sec
const TOTAL_OPERATING_TIME_BEFORE_BLOCK = 10; // sec

private $isBlocked = false;

public function work()
{
   while (true) {
      $this->work();
   }
}

public function timeLimits()
{
    $currentTime = time();
    $timePassed = $currentTime - $this->startTime;
    
    if ($timePassed > self::TOTAL_OPERATING_TIME_BEFORE_BLOCK && !$this->isBlocked) {
       $this->afterBlock = $currentTime + self::TOTAL_BLOCK_TIME;
       $this->isBlocked = true;
    }
    return $this->isBlocked && $currentTime < $this->afterBlock;
}

public function search($job)
{
        
    if ( $this->timeLimits() ) {
        return 'Blocked until:'.$this->afterBlock; 
    } 
    // db query, the rest of the code
    // it wont be executed if $this->timeLimits() return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works until the first block. So, after 10 seconds the script is blocked for 20 seconds. After those 20 seconds, the script is unblocked and works for another 10 seconds, and so on. Your solution works for the first block but after the script is unblocked is never goes into the block again after the next 20 seconds.

Comment: @Jake Did you create new instance every time or you are working with same instance ?

Comment: Frankly, I'm not sure what are you asking me. I believe it is the same instance because the script is in an infinity loop.

Comment: @Jake Could you provide more code, where you are calling this functionality ?

Comment: I have added the constructor. It is gearman worker and it is calling search function by this `$this->worker->addFunction("myfunction", array($this, "search"));`

Comment: So you are creating new instance of this class (once) and then in infinity loop you are calling this `timeLimits()` ?

Comment: Yes, on each call of the `search` function I'm checking `timeLimits()`